# why is my rails version dependent on what directory I'm on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, rubygems

I'm trying to figure what version of rails I got installed.. If I run on it on my home directory:

```
cd ~
rails -v
```

I get

```
Rails 3.2.13
```

However if I run it on the home directory of a ruby on rails project I just cloned:

```
cd /path/to/RoR/project
rails -v
```

I get

```
git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git (at bootstrap3) is not checked out. 
Please run `bundle install`
```

I'm confused.. why would it point out a missing bootstrap gem when I'm only looking for the rails version?

Comment: inside your project you have another `gems`

Comment: Also, if you've installed rbenv or rvm, the ruby version and gemset can change when you switch directory.

Comment: @Baldrickthat's why I did the `rvm --default 1.9.3` command.. but tell me (considering i'm a ruby/RoR noob), so the rails version automatically depends on the ruby language version?

Comment: @Monk_Code I'm not sure what your point is

Comment: its not about command its about the file present .... plz check is there a file callerd .rvmrc or .ruby-version file present in your ROR/project folder

Comment: @abbood The rails version depends on the first Rails gem found. `which rails` or `echo $GEM_PATH` may help you find the difference between the 2 directories. RVM also have the concept of 'gemset', but I'm not familiar with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails version is declared inside your Gemfile. If you navigate to folder containing Gemfile, RVM automatically switches to rails version specified in this folder (it does the same for Ruby version as well!).

Since you didn't run bundler, Gemfile.lock file is not valid and RVM cannot be sure it contains the right version of rails (some dependencies may require rails to be updated - for bundler rails is just a gem as any other). THat's why it asks you to run bundle.

Hope it makes sense. :)

Comment: i'm afraid it does :)